# Basic authentication using AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, http, afnetworking

I'm new in iOS development, How can I make an HTTP basic authentication using AFNetworking in Objective - C?

How to use it?

```
- (Void) setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername: (NSString *) username password: (NSString *) password
```

Answer (score 1):

You should create your own instance of AFHTTPClient, when you need to add headers or extend it. You can create sharedInstance as singleton and then call the instance method to set username and password.

```
+ (AFHTTPClient *)sharedClient{
    static AFHTTPClient *_sharedClient = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            _sharedClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"your_server_url"]];
        [_sharedClient setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];
    });

    return _sharedClient;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, but failed.

You are returning the following error:

```
Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html
NSLocalizedDescription = Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text/html.
```

I believe that the server is returning in `text/html` and the code is expecting JSON.

Answer (score -3):

You can use AFN to do most of your network request. Hope this can help you.

```
- (Void) setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername: (NSString *) username password: (NSString *) password {
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    //a NSDictionary parameter
    NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"name": username, @"pwd": password};
    [manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    //you can get JSON response in responseObject whether your request or wrong.
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
}
```

Comment: Would that not include the username and password as plain text in the URL? Definitely not good practice

Comment: It's a NSDictionary. "name" &"pwd" is the required string of the your website. username of course is string, you set your registered name and password. As you're using AFNetworking, nobody would see username and password in the url.

Comment: POST data is not sent in the URL, that has nothing to do with AFNetworking. But it is send as plain text in the body unless you are using https.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but failed.

You are returning the following error:

"Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text / html

NSLocalizedDescription = Request failed: unacceptable content-type: text / html".

I believe that the server is returning in text / html and the code is expecting JSON.